# Random sampling in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have an ensemble with a large number of samples in it ( say 100 different samples at different time in one ensemble). My ensemble looks like this

```
20
-166.26604715
C              -6.8775736572  0.7377700983   -1.2173950464
C              -6.3769524449  2.0225374370   -1.4858792908
C              -5.9530432940  -0.2309614983  -0.7933107594
C              0.924046       0.593909       0.306394
C              0.578941       0.740133       0.786926
C              0.43637        0.332195       0.77888
C              0.100887       0.785084       0.835159
C              0.761209       0.496077       0.426298
C              0.945798       0.821802       0.709269
C              0.157828       0.119752       0.909685
C              0.868084       0.449256       0.705432
C              0.399686       0.645049       0.696163
C              0.300211       0.591664       0.956569
C              0.156318       0.796877       0.132388
C              0.548236       0.984306       0.823073
C              0.422985       0.964365       0.793915
C              0.173531       0.568816       0.93252
C              0.205224       0.0199054      0.84918
C              0.726009       0.758101       0.197576
C              0.924046       0.593909       0.306394
20
-166.45321715
C              -6.8775736572  0.7377700983   -1.2173950464
C              -6.3769524449  2.0225374370   -1.4858792908
C              -5.9530432940  -0.2309614983  -0.7933107594
C              0.924046       0.593909       0.306394
C              0.578941       0.740133       0.786926
C              0.43637        0.332195       0.77888
C              0.100887       0.785084       0.835159
C              0.761209       0.496077       0.426298
C              0.945798       0.821802       0.709269
C              0.157828       0.119752       0.909685
C              0.868084       0.449256       0.705432
C              0.399686       0.645049       0.696163
C              0.300211       0.591664       0.956569
C              0.156318       0.796877       0.132388
C              0.548236       0.984306       0.823073
C              0.422985       0.964365       0.793915
C              0.173531       0.568816       0.93252
C              0.205224       0.0199054      0.84918
C              0.726009       0.758101       0.197576
C              0.924046       0.593909       0.306394
20
-166.41234567
..
..
continues
```

Where the first line represents the number of atoms so   \s+20  is my repeating pattern and it repeats after 22nd lines – the second line represents energy and from third line on – spatial coordinates (x, y, z). I want to randomly sample out for example just 4 samples (out of 100 in this example so 4*22 = 88 lines).Each sample (4 samples) should have the same data structure as shown above (2 headers + 20 lines) – I think I could use random number generators in python but because I am using bash for rest of the code I would like to see if there is a way in bash. Thanks in advance!

Comment: one (general) idea: read 1st number (`106` in this case); generate 20 random numbers between 1 and 106 (store as indices in an array?), start reading the 104 lines of coordinates checking each one's line number (1 to 106) with the list of random numbers (eg, current line number is an index in the array) and if a match then 'keep' said row

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: You're talking about "the second line", but the second line is _blank_. Please make sure your sample is exactly identical to your real data, including spacing.

Comment: BTW, if you want to work with floating-point math natively, you're better off writing your logic in awk than in bash.

Comment: does your input file contain blank lines (as shown in the sample)? if not, please update the question with an actual sample from the file (eg, `head filename`)

Comment: This is best done is awk, ruby, perl, etc. If you are doing the rest of something in Bash, just read the output line-by-line into a Bash loop and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample file is not proper for testing. So I created this one and changed 106 to 20 to keep it small

```
20
-166.26604715
C              -6.8775736572  0.7377700983   -1.2173950464
C              -6.3769524449  2.0225374370   -1.4858792908
C              -5.9530432940  -0.2309614983  -0.7933107594
C              0.924046       0.593909       0.306394
C              0.578941       0.740133       0.786926
C              0.43637        0.332195       0.77888
C              0.100887       0.785084       0.835159
C              0.761209       0.496077       0.426298
C              0.945798       0.821802       0.709269
C              0.157828       0.119752       0.909685
C              0.868084       0.449256       0.705432
C              0.399686       0.645049       0.696163
C              0.300211       0.591664       0.956569
C              0.156318       0.796877       0.132388
C              0.548236       0.984306       0.823073
C              0.422985       0.964365       0.793915
C              0.173531       0.568816       0.93252
C              0.205224       0.0199054      0.84918
C              0.726009       0.758101       0.197576
C              0.924046       0.593909       0.306394
```

So, the goal is to create a random sample of size N from the records starting line 3 to 22 (2 headers + 20 records).

```
$ awk -v s=4 'NR==1 {n=$1} 
              NR<3; 
              NR>2 && NR<=n+2 {print | "shuf -n"s}' file

20
-166.26604715
C              0.945798       0.821802       0.709269
C              0.548236       0.984306       0.823073
C              0.157828       0.119752       0.909685
C              0.422985       0.964365       0.793915
```

Here I picked the sample size as 4. Reads the number of records, prints the first two lines and samples requested records out of the number of records specified.

Note that this is sampling without replacement, meaning the same record can not be picked more than once, usually that's what is desired.

You may want to print the new number of records on top perhaps, but that's an easy change, left as an exercise...

**UPDATE**

For multiple data sets in the same structure (actually the number of records don't have to be the same) you need these modifications.

```
$ awk -v s=4 'BEGIN  {cmd="shuf -n"s; n=-2} 
              r==n+2 {n=$1; close(cmd)} 
                     {r=(NR-1)%(n+2)+1} 
              r<=2; 
              r>2 && r<=n+2 {print | cmd }' file.3
20
-166.26604715
C              0.422985       0.964365       0.793915
C              0.205224       0.0199054      0.84918
C              0.399686       0.645049       0.696163
C              0.726009       0.758101       0.197576
20
-166.26604715
C              0.43637        0.332195       0.77888
C              0.761209       0.496077       0.426298
C              -6.3769524449  2.0225374370   -1.4858792908
C              0.205224       0.0199054      0.84918
20
-166.26604715
C              0.156318       0.796877       0.132388
C              0.157828       0.119752       0.909685
C              -6.8775736572  0.7377700983   -1.2173950464
C              -5.9530432940  -0.2309614983  -0.7933107594
```

`r` is the relative position index within data set, and some special handling is required for line 1 (hence n=-2}. Also need to close the command after each data set to flush the buffers. Otherwise the logic is essentially the same with `NR` replaced with `r`

Comment: thanks but I am trying to achieve something different: so as in your example lets say N = 20 BUT this N=20 sample appears multiple times say 100 different times so my total number of lines would be 22 times 100  = 2200 and when I collect random sampling of 4 for example - its not just the four lines but 4 * 22 lines (4 N samples where each sample must have the SAME structure i.e.  2 headers + 20 records.